# Степень важности вопросов Debconf

Tags: python, linux, debian

Как из python-скрипта узнать наименьший уровень вопроса, который интерактивно задаёт Debconf? Есть ли способ лучший, чем парсить вывод команды `debconf-show debconf`?

И ещё, как узнать степени важности вопросов, которые задаёт Debconf по конкретному пакету (интересует наибольшая степень важности)? Это тоже нужно делать из python-скрипта.